# Debugging a bundled executable that runs with console, but not without

Tags: python, debugging, exe, pyinstaller

I am working on a script (a PyQt5 GUI application) that works fine as is, also works as intended on an exe created with console. I cannot get rid of the console though, as it crashes immediately with "Fatal error".

Is it possible to get detailed information on what the issue is? I tried `debug=True` in the script spec, it shows all sorts of process messages, tries to run the main file and crashes with the same fatal error. I have also added the following piece of code in the beginning to redirect all the print messages:

```
file = open('output.txt', 'a')
sys.stdout = file
main.run()
file.close()
```

Again, this runs fine as is, but converting it to non-console exe makes it crash immediately.

Can someone please let me know how to find detailed information about a "Fatal Error" issue?

Thanks.

Comment: On double clicking the exe, there is a popup saying "Fatal Error detected. Failed to execute script main". That's it. There is nothing helpful to suggest where I should look to fix the issue. If I create the exe with a console, the program works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is strange behavior that I have no explanation for. But since you asked for ways to get more debugging information, in a situation where running *without* a console attached seems to cause the problem, I would recommend the following.

First, if you redirect `stdout` to a file, that's good thinking, but you should redirect `stderr` as well.

Better, use Python's [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) module, which is part of the standard library, to write error tracebacks to a file. The added advantage is that the log file may also catch valuable debug information from the libraries involved, as `logging` is the commonly used way to report non-critical errors and warnings.

To demonstrate:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='log.txt', level=logging.DEBUG)
try:
    raise OSError('Emulated exception to be traced back to in log file.')
except Exception:
    logging.error('A critical error occurred.', exc_info=True)
```

Here, you tell it to write all log information to a file named `log.txt` in the same folder as the `.exe`. You should wrap the `try: ... except:` block around the main entry point (`main.run()` in your example). The `exc_info=True` option makes sure the full error traceback of the previously unhandled exception is included in the log file.

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Finally got it to work after checking the logs. I had to modify all subprocess calls to include STDERR and STDIN, but the biggest culprit was a call to python's faulthandler, which pyinstaller did not like at all. After commenting that line, I can now see and use the UI. Thank you!